# MongoDB "j must be numeric or a boolean value"

Tags: mongodb

I've set up my own local mongodb (v. 3.0.2) instance on a local ubuntu version (14.10) and I'm using [genghis](http://genghisapp.com/)(v. 2.3.11) to visualize it. My programm is able to create new documents in the database, but when I try to save a newly created document or delete a document in genghis it always returns "j must be numeric or a boolean value" but it still creates/deletes the document. The error doesn't show up when I edit a document. The only thing I could find when I tried to find a solution on google was this: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/write_concern_options.cpp which makes me think that it's a problem with my mongodb setup (and has nothing to do with genghis), but I do not know how to resolve this.

Comment: This sounds like something you should instead report to the [Genghis issue queue](https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/issues). It would also be helpful if you note whether you are using the PHP or Ruby version of Genghis and which driver version. The [`j:true` option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#j-option) likely refers to write concern, but that seems an odd choice to implement in a GUI.

Comment: I'm running the ruby version, but I doesn't really seem like a genghis issue since that error message comes directly from mongodb (check out the github page I linked, it has the exact same error message in it somewhere and it belongs to mongodb)

Comment: The error may be issued from the MongoDB server, but it's based on validating an option that has been provided in the client/application code :). I think your question is asking someone to debug Genghis, and as such is a better question for the Genghis author via the Github issue queue. You also haven't mentioned the specific version of the Ruby driver you are using, which may be relevant to reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the code against Mongo 2?

I ran into this same error when I tried connecting to Mongo 3 from a service that was using client libraries intended for Mongo 2.

Comment: Yes, this was the issue. We won't downgrade our mongo instance though so we changed the mongo client instead.